# How to make an element in a page the same visual width as another element exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that element **A**'s `width` is equal to **B**'s `width` so that they both visually appear to be the same.

I tried to do:

```css
$('#A').css('max-width', $('#B').css('width'));
```

But this doesn't work *the way I want it to*, because **B**'s `width` is 83%, so **A**'s max width becomes 83%.

This doesn't make **A** visually the same as it just becomes 83% of its parent element, which makes it appear bigger on the page.

Is there a way to calculate the visual width of **B** so I can use that as **A**'s max-width, using jQuery?

EDIT: I can't edit the document structure.

Comment: The best way to achieve this is with HTML and CSS alone. Using JS as a crutch for the UI is a really bad idea, for a variety or reasons. To help you with this we would need to see the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: The width is in pixels, not in %. JQuery reads and applies the calculated/rendered width, not the specified width in the CSS. Also it would help a lot to have the corresponding HTML

Comment: Try something like this `$('#A').css('max-width', $('#B').outerWidth());`

Comment: Why are you setting max-width? Max-width restricts how wide it can go..if it isn't already at that width, then setting max width will do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via javascript only, [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) should do :

> The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout width of an element as an integer.

```js
var myW = document.querySelector("#a").offsetWidth;
document.querySelector("#b").style.width=myW+"px";
```

```css
p {float:left;clear:left;border:solid;margin:1px 1em;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<p id="a">some content to give a width</p>
<p id="b">:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be setting [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width), not [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).

```
$('#A').css('width', $('#B').width() )
```

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGrMoK

Max-width restricts how wide an element can be - if it isn't already at the width you set as max width, then max-width won't have any effect. Width tells an element how wide it ***should be***.